# Godaddy WordPress 408error on linux

Tags: linux, android, wordpress, timeout, godaddy

I have a small website I'm starting on godaddy through their wordpress hosting platform. I can access my sites admin pages (/wp-admin) on all my devices but only seem to be able to do edits on ones running Windows.

My Linux (Arch) PC and Android phone both get 408 errors when submitting updates to the site.

I have 2 windows laptops both able to do edits but my Linux machine and my phone can't.

Has anyone had this before? Could you help me identify where the fault lies; me, godaddy servers, my router, my ISP...

Comment: Questions about installing and maintaining WordPress belong on WordPress.SE

Comment: Ok, thanks was bumped to here from another SE site. But will try again.

Comment: Don't do anything just yet. Like you said the problem could be anywhere.